# Remove item from list of list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, int

I have a problem with haskell fuction. I want to remove specific elements from list o list [[Int]]

There're many easy way to remove element in list [Int]

for example

```
removeItem :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeItem _ []                 = []
removeItem x (y:ys) | x == y    = removeItem x ys
                    | otherwise = y : removeItem x ys
```

but I can't write

```
removeItem :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
```

it should give a result:

> removeItem 1 [[1],[2,2],[3],[1]]
>
> ```
>   [[],[2,2],[3],[]]
> ```

Can anybody help me

Comment: Can you show your attempt at solving this problem and the error or where you got stuck?

Answer (score 5):

So you can't have `removeItem` both be `Int -> [Int] -> [Int]` and `Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]`. Instead, I'll call the latter `removeItem'`. You already know how to remove an item from just a regular list, so just use `map` to do it on a list of those lists. Implementation is then simple:

```
removeItem' :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
removeItem' x = map (removeItem x)
```